# Horizontal list giving me tons of issues

Tags: html, css, navigation

Honest to god, I'm two hours deep into this issue - the submenu simply will not style correctly, and regardless of how many lists I compare mine to, I cannot seem to make it look right.

**The site:**
http://blacktiephotographers.com/ - you have to click "enter" to see the list, sorry for that.

**The issue:**
The sub-list under the "corporate" category - I want the hovered item to fill the entire width of the sub- UL. As you can see, the black only fills about 80% of the ul's width.

The code I am using:

```
<div id="navigation-menu-container">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" id="nav-home" class="noSlide <?php if (is_home() || is_front_page()) { echo "curr-page-nav"; }?>"><span class="nav-hidden">HOME</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(838); ?>" id="nav-about" class="noSlide <?php if (is_page(838)) { echo "curr-page-nav";}?>"><span class="nav-hidden">ABOUT</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(1033); ?>" id="nav-wedding" class="noSlide <?php if (is_page(1033)) { echo "curr-page-nav";}?>"><span class="nav-hidden">WEDDINGS</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(1303); ?>" id="nav-mitzvah" class="noSlide <?php if (is_page(1303)) { echo "curr-page-nav";}?>"><span class="nav-hidden">MITZVAHS</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(1530); ?>" id="nav-celebration" class="noSlide <?php if (is_page(1530)) { echo "curr-page-nav";}?>"><span class="nav-hidden">CELEBRATIONS</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="nav-corporate" class="accordionButton <?php if (is_page(1635) || is_page(1909)) { echo "curr-page-nav";}?>"><span class="nav-hidden">CORPORATE</span></a>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(1635); ?>" id="nav-meeting" class="subitem"><span class="nav-hidden">MEETINGS</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(1909); ?>" id="nav-event" class="subitem"><span class="nav-hidden">EVENTS</span></a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(831); ?>" id="nav-testimonial" class="noSlide <?php if (is_page(831)) { echo "curr-page-nav";}?>"><span class="nav-hidden">TESTIMONIALS</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_page_link(874); ?>" id="nav-associate" class="noSlide <?php if (is_page(874)) { echo "curr-page-nav";}?>"><span class="nav-hidden">ASSOCIATES</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I've checked out my styles numerous times, cannot seem to make any of the above changes.

Here is a screenshot: [What the source code looks like for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkOwh.png)

Comment: Which browsers have you tested? (edit: reproduced here with Firefox 14.0.1)

Comment: Looked at the code and I have no idea what's what. Can you post the related styles and navbar code?

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest using a `<ul>` and `<li>` instead of what you have at the minute.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Nafhr/

Comment: I am using ul and li - what do you mean?

Comment: Your div `<div id="navigation-menu-container">` does not have an unordered list in it

Comment: No you're using 'a's and spans with ids and classes in place of ul and li.

Comment: There is an unordered list inside of the element with the id of "navigation-menu-container"

Comment: No, the only unordered lists on that web page (I control + F'd) are your "contact us" navigation and footer. The main navigation uses a div, with `<a>` and `<span>`

Comment: After reading your edited original post, its quite obvious we aren't looking at the same site.

Comment: somehow you are reaching an old, cached version. I'm about to attach a screenshot.

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing as Andy. I have cleared my cache and cookies and I have tried it in both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

can you provide a screen shot of how its supposed to behave..

Also in FF3 the sub menu is showing behind the main image instead of in front.. you need to add zindex: 9999; to get it to lay on top of the image.. and make sure your positioning is relative..

Comment: DesignedbyJackie, I think this would fit better as a comment rather than as an answer.